# rewriting external links (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to make photo hosting site external url (http://ipic.su) to open over https protocol from my site. This photo hosting has both http and https versions, so sometimes my users post http links wich causes mixed content warnings for users on my site.

I think this probably can be achieved by auto replacing http:// with https:// in url using some function?

Comment: How do they post these links? As comments or something else?

Comment: I have guest posting plugin, so it is their own posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `the_content` filter.

E.g, a very simplistic approach:

```
function ipic_to_https_filter($content) {
  $new_content = str_replace('http://ipic.su', 'https://ipic.su', $content);
  return $new_content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'ipic_to_https_filter' );
```

Comment: Looking good at firs sight and I don`t know why, but this code removes all content from my posts :)

Comment: Oh, as I can see you edited your post. Now code works like a charm, many thanks to you